# Get total working hours from SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an attendance SQL table that stores the start and end day's punch of employee.  Each punch (punch in and punch out) is in a separate record.

I want to calculate the total working hour of each employee for a requested month.

I tried to make a scalar function that takes two dates and employee ID and return the calculation of the above task, but it calculate only the difference of one date between all dates.

The data is like this:

```
000781  2015-08-14  08:37:00 AM     EMPIN    539309898   
000781  2015-08-14  08:09:48 PM     EMPOUT   539309886
```

My code is:

```
@FromDate NVARCHAR(10)
,@ToDate NVARCHAR(10)
,@EmpID NVARCHAR(6)


CONVERT(NVARCHAR,DATEDIFF(HOUR

,(SELECT Time from PERS_Attendance att where attt.date between convert(date,@fromDate) AND CONVERT(Date,@toDate)
AND (EmpID= @EmpID OR ISNULL(@EmpID, '') = '') AND Funckey = 'EMPIN')

,(SELECT Time from PERS_Attendance att where attt.date between convert(date,@fromDate) AND CONVERT(Date,@toDate)
AND (EmpID= @EmpID OR ISNULL(@EmpID, '') = '') AND Funckey = 'EMPOUT') ))

FROM PERS_Attendance attt
```

Comment: Think this should be fairly generic across servers, but which flavour of SQL are you working with?

Comment: Also, I assume there won't be problems due to people working after midnight?

Comment: i'm working with sql 2012..the employees have many shifts, example: an employee can work from 08:00 AM to 01:00 PM and can return from 03:00 PM to 09:00 PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more approach that I think is simple and efficient.

- It doesn't require modern functions like `LEAD`
- it works correctly if the same person goes in and out several times during the same day
- it works correctly if the person stays in over the midnight or even for several days in a row
- it works correctly if the period when person is "in" overlaps the start OR end date-time.
- **it does assume that data is correct**, i.e. each "in" is matched by "out", except possibly the last one.

Here is an illustration of a time-line. Note that `start` time happens when a person was "in" and `end` time also happens when a person was still "in":

All we need to do it calculate a plain sum of time differences between each event (both `in` and `out`) and `start` time, then do the same for `end` time. If event is `in`, the added duration should have a positive sign, if event is `out`, the added duration should have a negative sign. The final result is a difference between sum for end time and sum for start time.

```
summing for start:
                              |---| +

                       |----------| -
                |-----------------| +

       |--------------------------| -
  |-------------------------------| +

--|====|--------|======|------|===|=====|---|==|---|===|====|----|=====|--- time
  in   out      in     out    in  start out in out in  end  out  in    out

summing for end:

                                                   |---| +

                                               |-------| -
                                            |----------| +

                                        |--------------| -
                              |------------------------| +

                       |-------------------------------| -
                |--------------------------------------| +

       |-----------------------------------------------| -
  |----------------------------------------------------| +
```

I would recommend to calculate durations in minutes and then divide result by 60 to get hours, but it really depends on your requirements. By the way, it is a bad idea to store dates as `NVARCHAR`.

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2015-08-01 00:00:00';
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '2015-09-01 00:00:00';
DECLARE @EmpID nvarchar(6) = NULL;

WITH
CTE_Start
AS
(
    SELECT
        EmpID
        ,SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, (CAST(att.[date] AS datetime) + att.[Time]), @StartDate)
            * CASE WHEN Funckey = 'EMPIN' THEN +1 ELSE -1 END) AS SumStart
    FROM
        PERS_Attendance AS att
    WHERE
        (EmpID = @EmpID OR @EmpID IS NULL)
        AND att.[date] < @StartDate
    GROUP BY EmpID
)
,CTE_End
AS
(
    SELECT
        EmpID
        ,SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, (CAST(att.[date] AS datetime) + att.[Time]), @StartDate)
            * CASE WHEN Funckey = 'EMPIN' THEN +1 ELSE -1 END) AS SumEnd
    FROM
        PERS_Attendance AS att
    WHERE
        (EmpID = @EmpID OR @EmpID IS NULL)
        AND att.[date] < @EndDate
    GROUP BY EmpID
)
SELECT
    CTE_End.EmpID
    ,(SumEnd - ISNULL(SumStart, 0)) / 60.0 AS SumHours
FROM
    CTE_End
    LEFT JOIN CTE_Start ON CTE_Start.EmpID = CTE_End.EmpID
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

There is `LEFT JOIN` between sums for end and start times, because there can be `EmpID` that has no records before the start time.

`OPTION(RECOMPILE)` is useful when you use [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html). If `@EmpID` is `NULL`, you'll get results for all people, if it is not `NULL`, you'll get result just for one person.

If you need just one number (a grand total) for all people, then wrap the calculation in the last `SELECT` into `SUM()`. If you always want a grand total for all people, then remove `@EmpID` parameter altogether.

It would be a good idea to have an index on `(EmpID,date)`.

Comment: hello Vladimir Baranov, thanks for your participation, your solution is right when you store the time in the same field of date like **('2015-08-01 12:30:00')** but in my example i have the time separated from date as i mentioned in my question..so in this case your solution doesn't work

Comment: and does **OPTION(RECOMPILE)** works on SQL 2012 or older? because according to my knowledge, it works only on SQL 2014 and 2016 preview

Comment: Your question doesn't have a definition of your table and I'm not good at guessing. In any case, you can always combine date and time together to form a `datetime`. `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` works correctly starting from 2008 - read the article [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) by Erland Sommarskog.

Comment: dear Vladimir, if you read my question correctly, you can see that i have put the way in which the data is storing..the time data is in a separated column.. thank you

Comment: Sorry, all I could see was two rows with sample data without indication of column names and column types. It didn't occur to me that your store dates and times in two columns. You must have substantial reasons for storing date and time separately instead of simple `datetime` or `datetime2`. This kind of decision is usually driven by the queries that you anticipate and what indexes would be optimal for your queries. In any case, in this query it is easy to combine them as you suggested in the edit.

Comment: i have no reason storing date and time separately instead of simple datetime, it's an old system and old logic thinking..and it's difficult to make changes..

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MonthlyHoursByEmpID] 
(
@StartDate Date,
@EndDate Date,
@Employee NVARCHAR(6)
)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @TotalHours FLOAT
DECLARE @In TABLE ([Date] Date, [Time] Time)
DECLARE @Out TABLE ([Date] Date, [Time] Time)

INSERT INTO @In([Date], [Time])
SELECT [Date], [Time]
FROM PERS_Attendance
WHERE [EmpID] = @Employee AND [Funckey] = 'EMPIN' AND ([Date] > @StartDate AND [Date] < @EndDate)

INSERT INTO @Out([Date], [Time])
SELECT [Date], [Time]
FROM PERS_Attendance
WHERE [EmpID] = @Employee AND [Funckey] = 'EMPOUT' AND ([Date] > @StartDate AND [Date] < @EndDate)

SET @TotalHours = (SELECT SUM(CONVERT([float],datediff(minute,I.[Time], O.[Time]))/(60))
FROM @in I
INNER JOIN @Out O
ON I.[Date] = O.[Date])

RETURN @TotalHours

END
```

Comment: How would it work if somebody came `in` and `out` several times during the same day?

Comment: You're right - it wouldn't work for multiple in / outs on the same day or if an employee came in one day and went out on a different day.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the entries are properly paired (`in -> out -> in -> out -> in` etc).

**SQL Server 2012 and later:**

```
DECLARE @Year   int = 2015
DECLARE @Month  int = 8

;WITH
    cte AS (
        SELECT  EmpID,
                InDate = LAG([Date], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY [Date]),
                OutDate = [Date],
                HoursWorked = DATEDIFF(hour, LAG([Date], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY [Date]), [Date]),
                Funckey
        FROM    PERS_Attendance
    )

SELECT  EmpID,
        TotalHours = SUM(HoursWorked)
FROM    cte
WHERE   Funckey = 'EMPOUT'
        AND YEAR(InDate) = @Year
        AND MONTH(InDate) = @Month
GROUP BY EmpID
```

**SQL Server 2005 and later:**

```
;WITH
    cte1 AS (
        SELECT  *,
                rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY [Date])
        FROM    PERS_Attendance
    ),
    cte2 AS (
        SELECT      a.EmpID, b.[Date] As InDate, a.[Date] AS OutDate,
                    HoursWorked = DATEDIFF(hour, b.[Date], a.[Date])
        FROM        cte1    a
        LEFT  JOIN  cte1    b   ON a.EmpID = b.EmpID and a.rn = b.rn + 1
        WHERE       a.Funckey = 'EMPOUT'
    )

SELECT  EmpID,
        TotalHours = SUM(HoursWorked)
FROM    cte2
WHERE   YEAR(InDate) = @Year
        AND MONTH(InDate) = @Month
GROUP BY EmpID
```

Comment: The question is how to "calculate the total working hour of each employee for a requested month." Where does your answer accept a month, sum the hours worked per employee and handle any necessary clipping for the midnight shift at either end of the month?

Comment: @ZoffDino, how would it work if somebody came `in` on `2015-07-30 15:00:00` and came `out` on `2015-08-02 10:00:00` ?